# Replace all requested images with test.jpg in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to replace all requested images with a test image inside my .htaccess file
(running Apache2.2/Coldfusion8) like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|?:JPE?G|gif|png)$ test.jpg 
</IfModule>
```

The test.jpg is in the same folder as my .htaccess file, which I have cleared everything from except the above snippet. 
Problem is, still nothing happens.

**Question:**
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
Must be something in the httpd.conf settings I guess. I have set:

```
 AllowOverride All
```

in the document root directory, but still doesn't do anything.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `IfModule` tags.

Comment: try this instead `RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ test.jpg [NC,L]`. The second `?:` shouldn't be there/

Comment: doesn't work. I removed the IFMoldule, too, still the images don't get replaced.

Comment: also restarted Apache after every change to htaccess

Comment: try adding some random text to the htaccess and see if you get a 500 error message. If not, htaccess is not enabled.

Comment: @Gerben - you want to make your last comment an answer...? After setting directory to ALL and LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so it worked... Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding some random text to the htaccess and see if you get a 500 error message. If not, htaccess is not enabled.